# Error : The getter 'xrethrow' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'

Tags: binding, assets

This error occures when I add assets in pubspec.yaml file , after facing exception I comment out assets, now app is not running . I have no idea whats the error message is saying. Help Me
Error Message :
/C:/flutter_windows_2.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:670:7: Error: The getter 'xrethrow' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'.

- 'AssetBundleImageProvider' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart' ('/C:/flutter_windows_2.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'xrethrow'.
  xrethrow;
  ^^^^^^^^
  2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter_windows_2.0.0-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter_windows_2.0.0-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your network image file
edit from your location

```
[Your Flutter Location]/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart
```

and follow the instruction
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the only way to solve the problem was to uninstall Flutter and install it again.

I tried many approaches to solve the problem: `flutter clean`, deleting all `~/.pub-cache/hosted and ~/.pub-cache/git`, open/close IDE, shutting down/up the simulator, etc. And anything works. The only one that works was that I wrote first.

Here is the link to download and install Flutter: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/

Answer (score 0):

just change the `"xrethrow"/"srethrow"` to `"rethrow"` In below possition

/C:/flutter_windows_2.0.0-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:670:7: Error: The getter 'xrethrow' isn't defined for the class 'AssetBundleImageProvider'.

Or reinstall the Flutter package.

I am assuming its is a bug in flutter package. Its more likely to be someone had typing mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the error window, youll get link to the page, where this error has occur. Now simply press clt+F or respective key shortcut for searching and type throw. Youll get the where you have mistyped the word. In my case, i accidently wrote 'orethrow' where it was 'rethrow'. After correcting it, its working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: basically first navigate to the image_provider.dart page and then search "throw". then correct your spelling